# Get a Synology NAS to use External Drives?

Tags: nas, synology

I just started using a [Synology DS416J NAS](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS416j) Device.
I still have lots of external backup drives sitting around.

Can I get my Synology to automatically back up my files to those drives as well (a RAID 1-like setup)? If the space is there, and if Synology can know what's where, I might as well use the capacity for further redundancy.

Comment: You will be unable to use an external drive as part RAID array in your Synology.  You make that single drive assessible to the network.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't mean as an 'official' RAID setup. I more mean - if I have data 'A' stored on my NAS, can I get it to copy 'A' or parts of 'A' to other external drives on a regular basis, for added redundancy?

Comment: A disk connected to your NAS to the USB port would become network storage the same way if you connected it to your routers USB port